# Question page is not rendering latest edit

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits

I refer to:

[Get all pairwise combinations from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40092474/674039)

The most recent revision looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40092474/4

The site looks to be rendering an older revision.

The [revision history table](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40092474/revisions) also shows incorrect details, it says

> added 43 characters in body; edited title

Comment: Yep, the HTML source sent by SO's server does not reflect your edit

Comment: [shouldiblamecaching.com](https://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Comment: 4 days ago is too long to blame caching. The problem may in fact be related to a cache, but if so, it's a *stuck* cache, and thus still a bug.

Answer (score 8):

I have no idea how this happened. The last revision was indeed saved differently than the *body* of the post.

Some background on what happens when you save is that the HTML content is generated at that point, based on the current Markdown content - that way when the post is loaded, we just read the HTML content from the database and don’t have to translate the Markdown into HTML each time. For some reason, the latest HTML content did not save in the database when you saved this last revision.

I can’t replicate this and am going to consider this to be some weird one-time fluke (if someone can find a way to repro, I would be happy to look into it more).

Your edit is now showing on the post (I had to rollback to the previous version and then resave in order to get it to stick).