# This question appears to have an unremovable tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, specific-question

The question: [The Input Function Doesn't Do Anything When I Click Enter in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165827)

The question shows up for me as being tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input)

The `c#` tag should not be there.

When I click to edit tags, however, it disappears from the list, only to show up again upon saving. I can't find any way to remove it. I even tried removing everything and then adding the `python` and `input` tags back; the `c#` tag still won't go away.

Comment: The [revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72165827/revisions) says it's not there, despite it showing up on the question page.

Comment: Well, that certainly justifies an inability to remove it. The bug, then, is that it shows up on the question page.

Comment: The API says moo - sorry - that [tag:c#] is on the [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=72165827&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Comment: The network request made has the correct payload without `c#` and returns success too. Quite an oddity

Comment: A successful attempt to edit also drops the attempt to edit tags and only saves the body.

Comment: I killed your bug, sorry. A *retag* fixes the problem.

Comment: However, you get a replacement bug! Now the edit history looks [even weirder](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72165827/revisions).

Comment: The edit history looks normal to me, except that it doesn't show the `c#` tag anywhere.

Comment: yeah, that's the bizarre part, @KarlKnechtel - apparently, [tag:c#] was purged from the post completely (even [the API returns](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=72165827&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) as if the post never even had the tag)!

Comment: Oof, I guess that's going to make it harder to convince the site maintainers that we aren't just making something up :)

Comment: I guess so :) Why did it not occur to me to take a screenshot before squashing it?

Comment: *Go with the (Stack Over-)  Flow..., Accept the Tag..., Peace-Peace...!, Don't fight...!, Follow the Vibe...! And gloubs-spoink-abracadabra..., the Tag is gone...!* [Yes we made  it...!] - Coming soon, the 'Stack Overflow' Blues...

Comment: Maybe it is related to [Question page is not rendering latest edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403007/question-page-is-not-rendering-latest-edit)? OP removed the tag within the grace period, hence it not showing up in the revision history, but for some reason the rendered post didn't update?

Comment: @Ivar unlikely - the API returned the c# tag up until I found the way to remove the tag. At which point it started to claim it was never there in revision 1. Something's wrong in the database.

Comment: @Oleg That doesn't exclude the fluke. It's very likely that an edit occurred at some point and the tags didn't get saved to Posts (where the system pulls from when rendering the question page) but did get saved to PostHistory (where the system pulls from for revision history and the editor).

Comment: Ah, @animuson, that's precisely what I call "something is wrong in the database" :) It does not imply that ya'll have grave problems but that the problem was not in the UI layer as suggested in comments above.

Comment: @animuson Another case [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421265/8967612). Some users [investigated the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421274/8967612), and it indicats that there were no edits to the question between the time the tag was not shown on the question and when it was.